# Число не ниже и не больше

Tags: javascript

```
Math.max(0, e.offsetX)
```

Не дает числу опуститься ниже 0, возможно ли указать аналогично в обратную сторону.

То есть число не может быть меньше 0 и не более 200. Без условий и доп фунций, стандартно предусмотрено ли в js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) и [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max), просто объедините их.

```
Math.min(Math.max(val, min), max);
```

Объединил в функцию для наглядности:

```js
function minmax(val, min, max) {
  return Math.min(Math.max(val, min), max);
}

console.log('minmax(val, 0, 200)');
console.log('val: 100, return: '+minmax(100, 0, 200));
console.log('val: -100, return: '+minmax(-100, 0, 200));
console.log('val: 200, return: '+minmax(200, 0, 200));
console.log('val: 0, return: '+minmax(0, 0, 200));
console.log('val: 222, return: '+minmax(222, 0, 200));
console.log('val: "не число", return: '+minmax('не число', 0, 200));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: none !important;}
```

Comment: Интересно, неужели увидев метод `max` не было желания загуглить `min` ?))

Comment: Дело в том, что на данном этапе max - не функция получения максимального из аргументов, это просто заклинание, чтобы `не давать числу опуститься ниже 0`